# SQL Query - Case When Min - Closest date to today

Tags: sql

I have a table with a list of Customer Agreements `[source.Agreements]`.
A Customer can have multiple Agreements with different `[Agreement End Date]`

I need to get the closest `[Agreement End Date]` and then assign it to an `[Agreement Window]`

**For Example:**

If between Jan - Jun then:

> `[Agreement Window]` = FY H2

If between Jul - Dec then:

> `[Agreement Window]` = FY H1.

The financial year is = (`[Agreement End Date]` - 1 year)

**Example:**

`ID` has `[Agreement End Date] = 2020-06-30`.  So, the `[Agreement Window] = 'FY19 H2'`.

However, when an `ID` has more than one `[Agreement End Date]`, and the second date is between July - December, it uses that date and not the `MIN` date.

**Example: (see image below)**

`ID` 1789 has three `[Agreement End Date] = '2018-05-31', '2018-09-30', '2019-03-30'`.
It should return:

> FY17 H2

but it returns

> FY17 H1

[image]

I've included the query I have tried below.  I think I need a second `MIN` statement but not sure how to do it with a `CASE` statement.

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATE
SET @dtDate = GETDATE();

select A.ID 
    ,min(case when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate then AgreementEndDate else '' end) as 'Agreement End Date'
    ,min(case when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate  and ((month(AgreementEndDate) >= 7 and month(AgreementEndDate) <= 12))  THEN 'FY' + convert(varchar(2),(FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H1'
              when AgreementEndDate>=@dtDate  and ((month(AgreementEndDate) >= 1 and month(AgreementEndDate) <= 6))   THEN 'FY' + convert(varchar(2),(FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H2'
        else null end) as 'Agreement Window'
from source.Agreements A
where A.ID IN ('1740','1789','7582645','2387732')
group by A.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATE

SET @dtDate = GETDATE();

WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AgreementEndDate ASC
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM [source].[dbo].Agreements A
    WHERE A.ID IN ('1740', '1789', '7582645', '2387732')
    )
SELECT ID
    , CASE WHEN AgreementEndDate >= @dtDate THEN AgreementEndDate ELSE '' END AS 'Agreement End Date'
    , CASE WHEN AgreementEndDate >= @dtDate AND ((month(AgreementEndDate) >= 7 AND month(AgreementEndDate) <= 12)) THEN 'FY' + convert(VARCHAR(2), (FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H1' 
    WHEN AgreementEndDate >= @dtDate AND ((month(AgreementEndDate) >= 1 AND month(AgreementEndDate) <= 6)) THEN 'FY' + convert(VARCHAR(2), (FORMAT(AgreementEndDate, 'yy') - 1)) + ' H2' 
    ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Agreement Window'
FROM cte
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

The content of the table and result as shown:

[image: example]

Comment: I think you can get rid of the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes Vashi... you can get rid of the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry I was short on time and removed the MIN() last minute but forgot to then remove the earlier required GROUP BY. Good call.